# Server crashes whenever I attempt to login MongoDB, Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to access my localserver, whenever I attempt to start the site and login, it crashes and I get a few different errors that I've posted below.

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/user/dev/P2/frontpage/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at /Users/user/dev/P2/frontpage/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14
    at /Users/user/dev/P2/frontpage/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:994:11
    at /Users/user/dev/P2/frontpage/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7
    at callback (/Users/user/dev/P2/frontpage/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/dev/P2/frontpage/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

I've tried re-installing Mongo but with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: show your connection string pls

Comment: are you able to connect to mongodb using mongo shell?

Comment: MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("MovieRecommender");
        var myobj = { name: name1, password: pass1, first_time_logged_in: true};

Comment: what is the url is you passing??